# Nested lookup fields not returning a value using getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()

Tags: apex

I'm wondering if this is expected behavior with getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().

My example:

```
// Custom_Object__r is a lookup to an object named Custom_Object__c
// Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r is a lookup to an object named Custom_Object_2__c
String query = 'SELECT Custom_Object__r.Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r.Custom_Field__c FROM Opportunity';
List<Opportunity> opps = Database.query(query);
for(Opportunity opp : opps) {
    Map<String, Object> fieldMap = opp.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    Custom_Object_2__c obj2 = (Custom_Object_2__c)fieldMap.get('Custom_Object__r.Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r');
    if(obj2 != null) {
        System.debug('obj2.Custom_Field__c: ' + obj2.Custom_Field__c);
    }
    System.debug(opp.Custom_Field__c); // outputs a value
}
```

The issue is that obj is never NOT null, despite the fact that I'm sure there is data in the results.

Is this expected with nested lookups?

Thanks.

Edit: I have tried using a direct query, rather than Database.query and I get the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access `Custom_Object__r.Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r` directly, you need the step in between. You have an example in the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

```
// Custom_Object__r is a lookup to an object named Custom_Object__c
// Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r is a lookup to an object named Custom_Object_2__c
String query = 'SELECT Custom_Object__r.Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r.Custom_Field__c FROM Opportunity';
List<Opportunity> opps = Database.query(query);
for(Opportunity opp : opps) {
    Map<String, Object> fieldMap = opp.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    Custom_Object__c obj1 = (Custom_Object__c)fieldMap.get('Custom_Object__r');
    if (obj1 != null) {
        Map<String, Object> fieldMap1 = obj1.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        Custom_Object_2__c obj2 = (Custom_Object_2__c)fieldMap1.get('Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r');
        if(obj2 != null) {
            System.debug('obj2.Custom_Field__c: ' + obj2.Custom_Field__c);
        }
    }
    // I guess here you forgot to paste Custom_Object__r.Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r
    System.debug(opp.Custom_Object__r.Custom_Object_Custom_Name__r.Custom_Field__c); // outputs a value
}
```